# Why didn't Korosensei use his absolute defence form against the orbital laser?

Tags: assassination-classroom

I've been rewatching S1, and something popped up in my mind the last few episodes: Why didn't Korosensei use his absolute defence form to protect himself against the second attack of the orbital laser? Isn't he supposed to be indistructable in that form?

Comment: the absolute defense form is still part of himself is it not, doesn't that mean that the things that penetrate his cells will tear it as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of the final episodes, Koro Sensei specifically states that the orbital laser is so powerful it will break through even his Ultimate Defense Form - after all, it was designed based on all of the data gathered both from the experiments conducted in places like the ISS, as well as from observation of Koro Sensei and the class.

And from an out-of-universe perspective, it was needed to be an inescapable situation, to set up everything that would happen in the finale.